# Can i gift one game twice on Steam?

Tags: steam

I’ve received a game on Steam as a gift. I’ve downloaded it and then it was put into my Steam inventory. I gifted it to a friend, and after that the game was still in my inventory. Can I give it twice without my friend losing his copy?

Comment: the random letters were just so it would let me post the question

Comment: Are you certain that you did not receive two copies of the game in your steam inventory?  If you've placed it in your games library to be downloaded, the game should have been removed from your inventory.  Also I know it sounds like a silly question on the outset, but I know of some games that have come with double copies or "guest" copies in the past.

Comment: As a sidenote, if the system is preventing you from posting a question, try adding more detail, rather than random letters.  One lets us help you better, the other shows incredibly poor effort and reduces your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I've noticed this before as well.  I think mine was a DOTA 2 gift.  I think if you try to gift it to someone else, it changes the recipient, thus removing it from the first friend's inbox.  After your friend accepts, then it should get removed from your inbox.  I'm sure this is set up this way for a reason.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Why delete [tag:steam-inventory] tag? Is it not specifically about it?

Comment: @theUg It is a pretty pointless tag to begin with.

Answer (score 8):

The item stays in your inventory until the person redeems the gift.

If you gift it to someone else, the first gift offer will expire.

Comment: Can you actually gift it twice? every time I have gifted something, the copy that I gifted never has the option to gift it again.

Comment: could we get a source for this?